# gcc a program without a main trying to insert a breakpoint for analysis

Tags: c, gdb, breakpoints

I was given a file which I need to analyze. It doesn't have a defined main, and I was trying to get it to read the breakpoints.

I was using gdb and got things with mains to work and solve, but this one seems different.  How would I be able to create a breakpoint so the loop just doesn't wait for user input but allows me to examine what the input is comparing to?

```
 (gdb) run
 Starting program: [directory here]
 Reading symbols from shared object read from target memory...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
 Loaded system supplied DSO at 0xffffe000
 (no debugging symbols found)
 (no debugging symbols found)
```

Comment: You can try breaking at the (expected) C library function calls.

Comment: which are what?  I am unsure which calls are being used

Comment: That's the point. If it prints out anything, breaks on some of the print functions. If it reads anything from user, try to do so also. You can also try to break at the loader and start debugging from there. You can also try `start` command instead of `run`.

Comment: i was checking the stdio lib, and trying to break on the input stuff, as it is asking for input.  that isnt working though.  I was trying all sorts of scans and gets.  Any other ideaS?

Comment: You can compile a random program and used gdb check for the name of the loader function (function before main() is called), then break for that function in the program you need to crack.